# Clojure printing functions: pr vs print

Tags: clojure

What is the difference between `pr`/`prn` and `print`/`println`?

When would one be used over the other?

Answer (score 34):

They differ in the following ways.

- `print`/`println` produce output intended for human consumption
- `pr`/`prn` produce output that may be read by the reader

So use the former functions when producing output for humans, and the latter for when producing output for other Clojure programs to consume.

In the case of `pr`/`prn`, strings will be quoted, and special characters escaped. Characters will also be escaped outside of strings.

For example:

```
=> (println "Hello\nworld" \!)
Hello
world !

=> (prn "Hello\nworld" \!)
"Hello\nworld" \!
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second line be the same as the first?

Comment: @Bobby, do you mean in the final example I give? Is so, then no -- the second line's output is suitable to be fed back into the reader (a piece of software), as if a programmer had typed it.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, in your second string you have the exclamation mark in the string instead of being an extra parameter (because that gives for me a different output)...was that intended?

Comment: @Bobby, ah, well spotted. Updated.