# Convert list of lists into string in Clojure

Tags: clojure

How do I convert a LazySeq which is a list of lists into a string that has the exact same structure and parantheses?

```
(def my-list (lazy-seq '((a b 0 1 x y) (a b 0 4 x y) (a b 0 3 x y) )))
(def string-list (print-to-string my-list ))

string-list
;; should return "((a b 0 1 x y) (a b 0 4 x y) (a b 0 3 x y) ))"
;; but returns "clojure.lang.LazySeq@72251662"
```

Comment: it's just `(str my-list)`

Comment: oh sorry I meant for a LazySeq this doesn't work

Comment: could you please update your question with the actual case then )

Answer (score 2):

for lazy sequences you can use `print-str`, which is alike simple `print` but writes the result to string.

```
user> (print-str my-list)
;;=> "((a b 0 1 x y) (a b 0 4 x y) (a b 0 3 x y))"
```

but beware, it obviously realizes the collection, and in case of infinite seq it would hang forever.

also you can override the print behaviour for any data type you want:

```
(defmethod print-method clojure.lang.LazySeq [data ^java.io.Writer w]
  (let [[firsts] (split-at 10 data)]
    (if (= 10 (count firsts))
      (.write w (str (seq firsts) " :: more"))
      (.write w (str (seq firsts))))))

user> (print-str (lazy-seq (range 1000)))
;;=> "(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) :: more"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the data as they are (or at least do your best with it), don't use `str`, but use `pr-str`.  It might make no difference for simple things, but it will for more complex data structures.

E.g

```
user=> (pr-str (lazy-seq '((a b 0 1 x y) (a b 0 4 x y) (a b 0 3 x y) )))
"((a b 0 1 x y) (a b 0 4 x y) (a b 0 3 x y))"
```

Comment: cfrick mentioned `pr` and @leetwinski mentioned `print`. The difference was the subject of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136766/clojure-printing-functions-pr-vs-print.